# How to install jQuery.stellar in react app

Tags: reactjs, stellar.js

Which npm module do I have to install to use the code below in my react app?

```
$(window).stellar()
```

Tried multiple solutions but still nothing works, and issue is quite simple

Answer (score 1):

`npm install --save markdalgleish/stellar.js#v0.6.2`

Source: https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js/issues/130

Comment: ```$(...).stellar is not a function``` still occurs